# WMS or ArcGIS MapServer draw geometry at point

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

I have a WMS service and use ArcGIS MapServer sometimes. These services connect to data source and get geometries as image.

I have a WMS or MapServer service that gets data from a database. But I want to show some temporary points on print view. So I need to show a point that my coordinates. I will send a point coordinate on WMS service or ArcGIS service it will show the point on response tile, but it will not be on database.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a WMS GetFeatureInfo request to retrieve values from your data, at any point location on your map.  The actual point location in the request is an image coordinates x,y or i,j depending on the WMS version, for the image created by the WMS GetMap request used to generate the image that you click on.